# Webrequest returns 401 but same request using postman works

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webclient, postman

I have a c# client that is calling a webapi web service (iis 6). I am able to execute my web calls successfully from postman - No Authentication (Normal tab).
The same call from the c# webclient fails.

Looking at the requests in fiddler I don't see a difference between the two.

Below is the request I am sending (postman  and webclient) no headers are set.

https://store.isswerver.com/api/details/Users - Succeeds from postman client

Returns 401 using c# client

```
_client = new WebClient();
_client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
_client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
 byte[] data = _client.DownloadData(string.Format("{0}/Users", _apiUrl));
```

The client does work if I run the website on my local machine.

What is different in the way postman is submitting the request?

Comment: HTTP 401 means Unauthorized so I would assume you are logged in when you do the request through the browser ?

Comment: What happens if you set _client.UseDefaultCredentials = true ?

Comment: _client.UseDefaultCredentials = true fixed it, I swear I had tried that Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check with a sniffer what Postman is actually sending on the wire and compare it with what you're sending for *any* kind of difference, both in the headers and the payload.

[401 Unauthorized](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2) usually means you haven't supplied authentication credentials, however servers can return whichever status code they want for whichever reason (e.g. there's nothing preventing them to return a 401 status if they don't like the user agent).